# Looking for a Meterpreter binary for android

Tags: android, meterpreter

I tried meterpreter for android. The apk that is generated by metasploit by giving remote host ip & port and then run on target phone. I found it as a handy tool to access my phone remotely.
I need a standalone meterpreter binary for android. So that I could directly run on android terminal emulator app and access my phone remotely. I don't need that generated apk file.

Please share here, link for standalone meterpreter binary file or Guide me how to make one.

Comment: Well usually what is done is you get a binary and rebuild it with your trojan. The closest thing is an example with debian files in linux : https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/binary-linux-trojan/

Answer (score 2):

you could try [drozer](https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/products/drozer/) by MWR Labs. it's pretty much meterpreter. it can be a little hard to get the hang of at first, but i'm pretty sure it'll do what you want. it does require an .apk install though.